# Is it possible to export video with comments on overlay of video using popcorn JS?

Tags: javascript, html, video, popcornjs

I am using porpcorn JS for adding annotations on video, I have created overlay on video and all annotations are rendered on video. Is there any way so that I can export video with embedded html content inside an `.mp4`-file. So I can play that video in any native player like VLC?

Comment: use a screen-recording software to make a whole new movie from the playing result.

Answer (score 1):

You're best of handling it *all* on the server side and simply playing the rendered video on the client. If the code on the client side is sufficiently complex you can consider the two following options:

## Easiest option: Client frame rendering, server video rendering

You can quite easily grab each frame from the video, draw it onto a canvas and next draw the annotations to the same canvas as well (using either custom code or a library like [html2canvas](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/)). Next the *easiest* thing to do would be to send all the frames one by one to the server and use a simple ffmpeg command (something like `ffmpeg -i img%03d.png -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p out.mp4`) to generate the mp4 which you would then send back to the client.

## Best, but hard option: Client frame rendering, client video rendering

'Of course' actually rendering the video on the client side is not impossible. Do note however that the only library I am aware of does not render `.mp4` files, but `.webm` files. Whether that's a problem is up to you. Either way, the library that is capable of doing this is called [whammy.js](https://github.com/antimatter15/whammy). Once again you would actually need to draw all the frames and annotations to a canvas which you then `encoder.add` to the `Whammy` video object. The API is pretty simple and to the point, however do note that I have no idea about how cross platform its support is.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: no

Long answer:
The MP4 container can hold XMP metadata so in theory someone could write an exporter but you would still need a player capable of using the XMP metadata and as far as I know VLC doesn't support it.